# Should I close stream if I get it by invoking an external API?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I use Jackrabbit (content repository) and I store files there. I get a stream reference like this:

```
final InputStream ds = dataProperty.getBinary().getStream();
```

Then I have created domain specific objects where I set the `ds` stream so that each object have a reference. Now, when I use it, should I close it? Why/why not? What happen if I do/don't?

I know the rule of not closing streams that you didn't create, but I don't know in this case.
I have a field like this which I set during the retrival of the object in my repository (not Jackrabbit, but repository as in DDD principle).

```
private InputStream data;
```

Comment: This is something that should be addressed by the documentation of the API from which you're getting the stream. If it's not mentioned by those docs, those docs are incomplete.

Comment: So if they say no, I should close the stream? What If the object (my own domain object) closes the stream, then later I just have to open it right? before I use it

Comment: @ Luke: I don't think most streams are re-openable.

Comment: So maybe keeping a reference to a stream like this isn't that good. Since the same object could be used many places and closing/opening maybe won't be possible?

Answer (score 1):

[Always close streams](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=8),

> Streams represent resources which you must always clean up explicitly, by calling the close method.

Comment: It's probably not actually an `InputStream`, but quite likely a subclass, which may well do something in `close`.

Answer (score 0):

Uncloased, unused streams = leaks of resources. Nothing more, so yes, close your streams.

Comment: The word in that sentence being "**your**", and I think that's the crux of the question. Do you close the stream you get from `ServletResponse#getOutputStream`, for instance? I suspect the reality is rather more complex than "yes, always close them."

Comment: I do. Closing output stream in your example doesn't have to close anyh underlying stream at all - oh yeah i forgot- there CAN be underlaying streams so we should always invoke close if we are not going to use them anymore. It is up to implementation to do proper actions (or just do nothing) while invoking `close()`